# Control styles used for cross-references in MS Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I often want to cross refernce headings in a document e.g "this will require extra work, as detailed in **New Functionality**". When I inset such a X-ref, it just shows as normal text and gives no indication it's a link unless you mouse-over it, which isn't helpful when printing.

Can I easily control some styles for X-refs, such as underlining? What about causing numbering from headings "See **1.2.3 Bananas** for more information"?

Answer (score 1):

You can get cross-references displayed with a "shading". 
To do so, go to Tools -> Options, View tab and select "Always" from the combo box under Field Shading.